# MetaTrader5 WebAPI demo account creation

Tags: python, webapi, metatrader5

I would like to create multiple demo accounts using a Python script

Using a simple Python script, I would like to create multiple MetaTrader5 demo accounts. I have a MetaTrader server running and I can create demo accounts manually, but is it even possible to create them automatically using the WebApi?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.